# how to split the content by some keyword by SQL in sqlsever?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, split

how to split the content by some keyword by SQL in sqlsever?

I have two table, t1 and t2, and I want to split some column in t2 by the word in t1.

```
t1
column1
a
bc
c
z

t2(based)
column1 column2
1        abcrrr    
2        cdt
3        e


t2(updated)
column1 column2
1        a
1        bc
1        rrr
2        c
2        dt
3        e
```

Is it possible to write a SQL sentence to update the t2 like above? I want this performance in SQLserver 2008.

The logic is, if the data in t1.column1 is the subString of some t2.column2, then split t2.column2 to two new row with the same t2.column1, but for the t2.column2 of new rows, one is the subString, other is the rest(with the sutStr removed).

Thanks!
Wawa

Comment: @Wawa:I have posted one answer for your updated query..plz check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_COL_SPLIT(@COL VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS @TPARTS TABLE ( PART VARCHAR(20) )
AS
BEGIN

;WITH CTE ( RNK ,AUTOID,COLUMN1,COL,SLNO)AS (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.AUTOID) AS RNK,T1.AUTOID,T1.COLUMN1,REPLACE(@COL,T1.COLUMN1,'') AS COL,0 FROM T1  
WHERE (LEN(REPLACE(@COL,T1.COLUMN1,''))<>LEN(@COL))   
UNION ALL
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.AUTOID) AS RNK,T1.AUTOID,T1.COLUMN1 ,REPLACE(COL,T1.COLUMN1,'') AS COL,SLNO+1 FROM CTE C   JOIN T1 
ON LEN(REPLACE(COL,T1.COLUMN1,''))<>LEN(COL)      )
INSERT INTO @TPARTS
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1 FROM CTE  WHERE RNK=1
UNION 
SELECT COL FROM CTE WHERE LEN(COL)=(SELECT MIN(LEN(COL)) FROM CTE)

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  @TPARTS)=0 INSERT INTO @TPARTS SELECT @COL

RETURN
END
```

Then use the below select statement to get the result

```
SELECT T2.COLUMN1,T3.PART FROM T2 CROSS APPLY FN_COL_SPLIT(T2.COLUMN2) T3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table(column1 int, column2 varchar(100))
insert into @t 
select 1,        'ab' union all     
select 2,        'cd' union all 
select 3,        'e' 

 select t1.column1,char(t2.number) as columns2 from @t as t1 
 inner join master..spt_values as t2 on t1.column2 like '%'+char(t2.number)+'%'
 where type='p' and number between 97 and  97+25
```

Comment: Awesome hardcoding, did you consider that there might be other values that he has not mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this with any set of characters.**

```
declare @t table(column1 int, column2 varchar(100))
insert into @t 
select 1,        'abc' union all     
select 2,        'cd' union all 
select 3,        'eyiuyiu' 
select * from @t
;WITH CTE as (
select column1,CASE when len(column2) >= 0 then left(column2,1) else column2 end as column2,RIGHT(column2,len(column2)-1) as rem from @t --where column1 = 1
union all
select t1.column1,CASE when len(rem) >= 0 then left(rem,1) else rem end as column2,RIGHT(rem,len(rem)-1) as rem from CTE c inner join @t t1
on c.column1=t1.column1 and CHARINDEX(c.rem,t1.column2,1) > 0
 )
select column1,column2 from cte order by 1
```

Comment: It seems that it is a good way to split the data to single char. But what I want is to split only in the case the t1.column1 is substr of t2.column2, I've update the test case.

Answer (score 0):

select t2.column1,t1.column1 from t1
 inner join t2 on t1.column1  like '%['+ t2.column2 +']%'

Comment: it seems that this sentence cant select the last row "e".